# Category Theory: Why arrows?

Tags: category-theory

Category Theory as far as I understood is about how objects are related to each other.

*So why do we then consider "directed" morphisms rather then "undirected" ones?*

I mean for example relations between sets rather than maps between sets as these are more general. Sure, plain relations can be covered within the category approach too but goin the other way around would be more plausible.

Comment: To only have to check half as much when verifying commutativity of a diagram?  :-)

Comment: I mean, it is because category theory is the study of relation by structure preserving maps. Maps are directed.

Comment: Have you had a look at [allegories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_(category_theory))? I mean, not that binary relations wouldn’t define arrows as well. Binary relations are directed.

Comment: Also *relations* are directed, so you still need an arrow.

Comment: Aaahhh =D you're right relations are directed too ...thx man thats it =D ...can u post this as answer?

Comment: Haha ^^ @EricTowers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since even relations can be expressed as arrows ...one could in principle also define relations as unordered pairs however they always simultaneously are given as ordered pairs so there's no gain in doing so